# How to include a function from an external file inside another?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have this code right now:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => { 
 function login() { 
  socket.name = 'myname';
 }
 //many more functions like the previous one here
});
```

I want to put all inner functions in an external file so I have a cleaner code. So I did this:

External file:

```
     login = function() { 
      socket.name = 'myname';
     }
```

Main file:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
 require("../chat/functions"); 
 login();
 //many more functions like the previous one here
});
```

But now I'm getting a `socket is not defined` error. I know I can kind of solve it if I include a parameter like this: `login();` but this will imply modifying the behavior of all my functions and I'm not quite okay with that. Is there any alternative out there?

Comment: By parameter, do you mean `login(socket)`? That's the best way to do it by far, it shouldn't involve changing any other code

Comment: Yes, with `login` its not so much trouble. But I have other functions that already have more than 4 parameters. Adding yet another one would make them look kinda messy.

Comment: The (barely worth mentioning) alternative is global variables. You'll need another argument. You might find a destructured object passed to all subfunctions as nice enough, though.

Comment: I tried global variables but it didnt work with sockets because it will get overwritten every time a new user connects. Or maybe Im not doing it right. Do you mind to elaborate on your suggestion please?

Comment: Are the different parameters that get passed to the other functions sometimes or always shared? For example, I'd assume most would want a reference to `socket`. Are the other arguments being used also often the same?

Comment: No, the other arguments are totally unrelated to socket and very specific for each function.

Answer (score 1):

Given your "socket" is defined as an object, then you could have two files:

1. external.js
2. main.js

```
// external.js
module.export = {
  login: (name) => {
    return name;
  },
  
  logout: () => {
    console.log('logout message')
  }
  
};

// main.js
const { login } = require('./external');

io.on('connection', (socket) => { 
 socket.name = login('myname');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It did occur to me that this might work but didnt test it. Seems like it works for now I just have a little issue. Lets say I have yet another file that includes the functions from external.js. Then it wont work there. Lets say: anotherfile.js `const { login } = require('./external'); function test() { login(); }` this will produce another `socket is not defined` error.